# UILabel with UIMenucontroller not resigning first responder with touch outside

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have subclassed UILabel to provide a copy menu and would like to add some type of effect that makes the UILabel stand out when this menu is displayed.

Right now I am trying to add and remove a border. It works fine however if the user touches the label and then touches outside of the label the border won't disappear although the copy menu does.

After adding some NSLog's it seems like resignfirstresponder is not being called when this occurs. What happens in the responder chain when this happens and how can I get the border to disappear in this event?

Code as follows :

```
@implementation CopyLabel

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if(action == @selector(copy:)) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    }
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    if([super becomeFirstResponder]) {
        self.highlighted = YES; 

        UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [menu setTargetRect:self.bounds inView:self];
        [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    if([super resignFirstResponder]) {
        self.highlighted = NO; 

        UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [menu setMenuVisible:NO animated:YES];
        [menu update];

        NSLog(@"Resign");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


- (void)copy:(id)sender {
    UIPasteboard *board = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [board setString:self.text];
    self.highlighted = NO;
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if([self isFirstResponder]) {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if([self becomeFirstResponder]) {

    } else {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    if(self.highlighted) {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: Change your method to override the (BOOL)canResignFirstResponer and see if that method is being called by the view hierarchy.  Once your logic is being executed, add a [self setsNeedsDisplay] after you update your highlighted property.

Comment: I overrode the canResignFirstResponder method but it does not fix the issue. It appears that if you touch somewhere outside of the UILabel after touching inside of it, it does not resignFirstResponder. If subsequently touching it again (after touching else where and the menu disappearing) it will resignFirst responder.

Comment: Okay.  The view you are receiving the touch in (not your label view).  You should intercept the touch or the associated event in your view controller and have it clean-up your UILabel sub-class' state and it's border.

Comment: Ok the view the gets touched is the main view, I thought touching the main view would cause it to become the first responder and the UILabel to resign first responder. Is there a way I can make the UIView become the first responder when touched resulting in the UILabel to resign the first responder?

Comment: UIResponder defaults to returning NO for the canBecomeFirstResponder method.  The view getting the touch declines becoming first responder, so it is still you label that is first responder and your code is not being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIMenuController posts a  UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification. When you listen for that notification (using NSNotificationCenter) you can send resignFirstResponder to your Label at the right time.

Example:

```
- (id)init... {
    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(editMenuHidden)
                                                 name:UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification 
                                               object:nil];
    ...
}

- (void)dealloc {
    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                name:UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification 
                                              object:nil];
    ...
}

- (void)editMenuHidden {
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

...
```